# Is it possible to create a 22 stage synchronous counter using multiple 4-bit synchronous counter?

Tags: counter

Is it possible to create a 22 stage synchronous counter by linking together multiple 4-bit synchronous counter, like SN74F163AN?

Comment: Yes it is possible to cascade counters but the maximum clock rate will be limited but the total enable cascade propagation delay. Look in various data sheets for a '163 type counter and you will find the suggested synchronous cascade connection scheme.

Comment: ... which is something you should have done before asking here.

Comment: @Dave, maybe u can find that for me in this link http://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/sn74f163a ?? Because I could not find any, except the following: This function is implemented by the ENP and ENT inputs and an RCO output. Both ENP and
ENT must be high to count, and ENT is fed forward to enable RCO. RCO, thus enabled, produces a
high-logic-level pulse while the count is 15 (HHHH). The high-logic-level overflow ripple-carry pulse can be used
to enable successive cascaded stages. Transitions at ENP or ENT are allowed, regardless of the level of CLK.

Comment: See Figures 1 and 2 (pages 21 and 22) in [this datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn54163.pdf). I guess you got unlucky with the one you found -- the information that we all know was there originally has been deleted.

Comment: Yeah I guess I am having a bad day :-P

Comment: My sympathies, but really, you should have been able to infer the required connections from the description you found.

Answer (score 4):

This type of counter can be cascaded to produce an N-bit synchronous counter. Some data sheets for this style of 4 bit counter show how the connections are done. The diagram below is from this [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn54163.pdf).

[image]

Please be aware of the note on the diagram that the maximum clocking rate is reduced by adding additional stages due to the propagation delay of the carry look ahead circuitry in each stage.

There is an alternate way to hook up the additional stages so that the maximum count frequency is not affected by more stages. See below:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. The [Datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74f163a.pdf) states:

> Both ENP and
>   ENT must be high to count, and ENT is fed forward to enable RCO. RCO, thus enabled, produces a
>   high-logic-level pulse while the count is 15 (HHHH). The high-logic-level overflow ripple-carry pulse can be used
>   to enable successive cascaded stages.

Source all counters from the same clock and use the carry to enable the next stage.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, certainly, but if you want to run at high frequencies you'll need to use the Fast Carry connection. This

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYinzQ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

will give you 24 bits.

If you just run the normal RC/ET connection, for long counter chains you'll run into limits caused by the need for the carry to propagate through the entire chain. In the case of a 74F163, worst-case propagation from clock to RC is 10 nsec, and worst-case propagation of ET to TC is 7.5 nsec, with an ET or EP setup time of 11 nsec. So, for a count of FFFFFE to FFFFFF, it will take 10 + (4 x 7.5) + 11 nsec or 51 nsec for the last counter to be ready for the next clock pulse. This effectively limits the counter chain to 20 MHz operation. With a fast carry, the RC/ET ripple has 15 clock cycles to settle, and can be disregarded. At the final count, the time required for the RC/EP is just 10 + 11 nsec, and the chain can count at 47 MHz, 27 MHz faster than the "regular" chain. This won't be quite true, of course, since with 5 loads on the first TC output, plus the added length of the connection, the propagation of the output will probably be delayed by a few nsec compared to the shorter RC/ET connections, but the speed gain will still be at least a factor of 2.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, you need to cascade the ICs using the "carry output" pin from the previous IC into the next IC "clock" pin.

Comment: -1 = Your suggestion does not lead to a totally synchronous counter. Each package unit is a being used as a ripple carry unit. A fully synchronous counter would use the exact same clock signal for every package.